# What is the difference between std::set and std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I am learning STL now. I read about `set` container. I have question when you want to use `set`? After reading [description of set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) it looks like it is useless because we can substitute it by `vector`. Could you say pros and cos for `vector` vs `set` containers. Thanks

Comment: Since you read about set, also read map. Then try comparing again!

Comment: [Choose your container with care](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_ZAqgwpqtF4MjQ5NmNlM2ItNTQxNS00MmEyLWFiODctNDk4YTY5MDRlYzQz)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

A `set` is ordered. It is *guaranteed* to remain in a specific ordering, according to a functor that you provide. No matter what elements you add or remove (unless you add a duplicate, which is not allowed in a `set`), it will always be ordered.

A `vector` has exactly and *only* the ordering you explicitly give it. Items in a `vector` are where you put them. If you put them in out of order, then they're out of order; you now need to `sort` the container to put them back in order.

Admittedly, `set` has relatively limited use. With proper discipline, one could insert items into a `vector` and keep it ordered. However, if you are constantly inserting and removing items from the container, `vector` will run into many issues. It will be doing a lot of copying/moving of elements and so forth, since it is effectively just an array.

The time it takes to insert an item into a `vector` is proportional to the number of items already in the `vector`. The time it takes to insert an item into a `set` is proportional to the *log₂* of the number of items. If the number of items is large, that's a huge difference. log₂(100,000) is ~16; that's a major speed improvement. The same goes for removal.

However, if you do all of your insertions at once, at initialization time, then there's no problem. You can insert everything into the `vector`, sort it (paying that price once), and then use standard algorithms for sorted `vectors` to find elements and iterate over the sorted list. And while iteration over the elements of a `set` isn't exactly slow, iterating over a `vector` is faster.

So there are cases where a sorted `vector` beats a `set`. That being said, you really shouldn't bother with the expense of this kind of optimization unless you know that it is necessary. So use a `set` unless you have experience with the kind of system you're writing (and thus know that you need that performance) or have profiling data in hand that tells you that you need a `vector` and not a `set`.

Comment: But isn't the `set` being ordered just an implementation detail? Mathematically speaking, a set has no order.

Comment: @PaulManta: A `std::set` isn't defined by math; it's defined by the C++ specification. And the specification states that it is ordered.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Why is "The time it takes to insert an item into a vector is proportional to the number of items already in the vector." ? -- Do you mean using insert() always and inserting not at the end? Can't you just use push_back() and add it in O(1)? especially since the user controls the ordering.

Comment: @Kingkong: "*Do you mean using insert() always and inserting not at the end?*" Yes. As stated in my answer, if you're adding and removing things from a *sorted* vector, then you have to add and remove them from *within* the vector. The user *doesn't* control the ordering; the sort order does.

Comment: "So use a set unless..."  Hmm..   Probably better to use Stroupstrup's advice:  "And, yes, my recomendation is to use std::vector by default. More generally, use a contiguous representation unless there is a good reason not to."

Comment: @Alex: In this case, no. If you're thinking about using `set`, then order is clearly important to you. Keeping a `std::vector` sorted requires significant effort. You basically have to build a type around the container. So I wouldn't suggest doing it unless you *know* there's a legitimate performance gain to be had. Of course, if you have access to `flat_set`, then yes, there's almost never a reason to use regular `set`.

Comment: One pitfall for Python users: a Python `set` is unordered, but a C++ `std::set` is ordered.

Comment: Since both can be ordered, I would say that the only real difference is that if you need duplicates, use "vector", otherwise, use "set".

Comment: Any claims here about std::set performance are basically hot air.
std::set only guarantees that it is O(ln(n)) but that says nothing about how fast it really is. It could be "5000+1000*ln(n)" operations, or 5*ln(n).
std::find on a vector is guaranteed O(n) - that just means that it could be slower for large numbers.
If the vector is sorted then in general it will outperform std::set - and that more and more the larger the data-size is due to its continuouse memory layout.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf: "*It could be "5000+1000*ln(n)" operations, or 5*ln(n).*" The same could be said for `vector`. The wording the standard uses to give `vector` O(n) insertion is the same guarantee that it gives to `set` for `O(log(n))` lookup. As far as the standard is concerned, it threats these guarantees identically. Yes, obviously, not all O(whatever) guarantees are made equal, but that's the nature of asymptotic analysis; it has nothing to do specifically with `vector` vs. `set`.

Answer (score 13):

They are different things: you decide how vectors are ordered, and you can also put as many equal things into a vector as you please. Sets are ordered in accordance to that set's internal rules (you may set the rules, but the set will deal with the ordering), and you cannot put multiple equal items into a set.

Of course you could maintain a vector of unique items, but your performance would suffer a lot when you do set-oriented operations. For example, assume that you have a set of 10000 items and a vector of 10000 distinct unordered items. Now suppose that you need to check if a value X is among the values in the set (or among the values in the vector). When X is not among the items, searching the vector would be some 100 times slower. You would see similar performance differences on calculating set unions and intersections.

To summarize, sets and vectors have different purposes. You can use a vector instead of a set, but it would require more work, and would likely hurt the performance rather severely.

Comment: +1 for uniqueness. i can't believe no one else bothered to point this out. for shame! uniqueness is the main benefit. and not to devalue that, but even the attendant ease of `erase`/`emplace`.often lead me to use `[unordered_]set`, even if it might in theory be slower - albeit usually in setup parts where speed is no concern and i'm only worried about being barely able to read the code later! e.g. i want to ensure an item is put in the container, but only once; it seems far nicer to write `set.emplace(it)` than `if (vec.find(it) != vec.end() ) { vec.emplace(it) }` (and more still for `erase`!)

Answer (score 8):

form [cpluplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) 
set:

> Sets are containers that store unique elements following a specific
>   order.

so the set is ordered AND item are uniquely represented

while vect:

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in
>   size.

so vector is in the order you fill it AND can hold multiple identical items

prefer set:

- if you wish to filter multiple identical values
- if you wish to parse items in a specified order (doing this in vector requires to specifically sort vector).

prefer vector:

- if you want to keep identical values
- if you wish to parse items in same order as you pushed them (assuming you don't process the vector order)

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. The accepted response is just too confusing to read. This is to the point.

Answer (score 7):

The simple difference is that set can contain only unique values, and it is sorted. So you can use it for the cases where you need to continuously sort the values after every insert / delete.

```
set<int> a;
vector<int> b;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int val = rand() % 10;
    a.insert(val);
    b.push_back(val);
}
cout << "--SET---\n"; for (auto i : a) cout << i << ","; cout << endl;
cout << "--VEC---\n"; for (auto j : b) cout << j << ","; cout << endl;
```

The output is

```
--SET---
0,1,2,4,7,8,9,
--VEC---
1,7,4,0,9,4,8,8,2,4,
```

Answer (score 6):

it is faster to search an item against a set than a vector (O(log(n)) vs O(n)). To search an item against a vector, you need to iterate all items in the vector, but the set use red-black tree to optimize the search, only a few item will be looked to find a match.

The set is ordered, it means you can only iterate it from smallest one to biggest one by order, or the reversed order.

But the vector is unordered, you can travel it by the insert order.

Comment: Not true.  You could do `std::binary_search` on a `std::vector`, which does logarithmic number of comparisons.

Comment: But a binary search is only valid if the vector is sorted.