# Performance(memory and speed wise) for a STL vector+sort+equality vs. unordered_set vs. using pure set

Tags: performance, algorithm, c++11, stl, unordered-set

I have the following scenario:

1. I have bunch of elements that does not need to be in consecutive order.
2. I will be able insert the elements very first time during initialization
3. I need to perform containerA == containerB operation.
4. The number of elements `N` can be 100 at most, but for going through avg. case analysis purpose, I will say `N` can be either 100, 10k or 100k

Given , my requirements std::set is not a good option. I can do all the element insertion in a vector using push_back `N*O(1)` and std::sort `O(NlogN)` them and do a equality comparison (N); total of `2N+NlogN` that would beat the std::set memory/speed easily.

The topic is already well reviewed here:
http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf
and here:
[What is the difference between std::set and std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686725/what-is-the-difference-between-stdset-and-stdvector)

Lets, move onto what if I use the new unordered_set. The insertion(`N*O(1))` + equality lookup(`N` avg. case) for `N` elements totals as `2N`.

Now, for unordered_set I need to create a hasher, which is not easy for my case. And I am guessing just the hashing part will cause this to go more than `2N` for my complicated data structure.

However, why for a simple unique_ptr value insertion, would someone get the following performance results:
http://kohei.us/2010/03/31/stl-container-performance-on-data-insertion/

It seems vector sort + equality would still work better than unordered_set, upto a large number of elements (100k). unordered_set does not use a red-black tree right? so where is this performance hit coming from?

A slightly relevant post is here:
[Performance of vector sort/unique/erase vs. copy to unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640107/performance-of-vector-sort-unique-erase-vs-copy-to-unordered-set)

Comment: You don't know how it performs in your case until you benchmark it. Furthermore, bear in mind that `==` on two `unordered_set`s is not guaranteed to be perfomed in linear time.

Comment: I was trying to understand this without benchmarking. I should be able to do a basic avg. case analysis in pen and paper. I am aware, that `unordered_set` comparison is not guaranteed to be linear. avg. case is `N`, worst case is `N sqaured` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/operator_cmp which is why i put down `N` in my analysis, since avg. case analysis is what I am interested in.

Comment: There are also issues related to locality of reference that are hard to crack with pen and paper analysis. The hash function plays an important role, too, and it is so hard to forecast how it will perform -- plus you don't give any detail here. I think your study is correct, but if you want to get things done just make a benchmark.

Comment: From what you describe, insertion time is not the dominant factor so you would want to optimize comparison. As I understand it, it boils down to a contest between a O(log(n)) time when using dichotomic search (on a sorted vector for instance) and something between O(1) and O(n) using hash tables. I would say it all depends on the cost and spreading power of your hash function.

Comment: @kuroineko: You cannot compare two collections in less than O(N), even if they are sorted, because every element of each collection needs to be examined. The binary search algorithm might have better average time for certain datasets, but its worst-case behaviour cannot be better that O(N).

Comment: @rici ??? I assumed you had some order on the elements, or else how could they be sorted?

Comment: @kuroineko: of course, but comparing two vectors still needs to be O(n). *Finding an element* in a sorted vector is O(log n).

Comment: @rici OK, now I see what the OP meant by "container". Well if the objects inside a collection are constant (as the question might indicate), why not compute a unique signature (some CRC or whatever) during insertion, and check the actual contents only if the signatures match? That would very likely be quite fast, assuming you can compute a discriminating enough signature.

Comment: @kuroineko: If that were easy, it would also be easy to write a hash function which OP says would be difficult. Comparing the lengths of the vectors before doing the comparison could be considered a very simple version of your suggestion -- here the CRC consists of simiply adding one for each element -- and on most datasets that would be a useful optimization, so I wouldn't discard the suggestion altogether, but it cannot replace a good container data structure.

Comment: @rici I'm not quite sure a CRC and and a hash function are the same. The hash function must spread the elements evenly on a small range, while a CRC32 for instance might discriminate them easily over a 4Gb range. That's why I think that might be worth a thought.

Comment: @kuroineko: A hash function conformant with the standard library needs to spread the elements evenly over the range of size_t. The main problem with your CRC is that it needs to be order independent (since the equality of two containers is not related to the order in which elements were inserted) and that requirement makes it much more difficult to provide good discrimination. You could use an order-dependent CRC after sorting, but the comparison after sorting is likely to be fast anyway, unless the containers are equal (in which case the CRC doesn't help either).

Comment: @rici I feel like there is something wrong with the initial question. If the containers are filled at init and you can sort them or compute signatures or whatever on them at your leisure, what does it matter which data structure are used underneath when we can very probably get a global information that tells us wheter two containers are equal or not 99.9% of the time?

Comment: @kuroineko: I suppose (based on my experience with similar problems) that OP means that the containers are not modified after creation, rather than that all the containers are created at program initialization. Consider for example the case where various subsets of a dataset are found using some search criteria with the aid of indexes, and one wants to know whether two of them are the same set of elements. Here the result sets are not modified after creation, but not predictable at program start-up.

Comment: @rici okay, but in that case you can easily compute a signature that has so high a chance to be unique that false positives will be close to nil. What I mean is, it is probably better to create a specific data structure for comparison purpose than relying on the underlying container lookup speed. For instance you could collate the CRC16 of each element into a sorted array (just a silly example off the top of my head) and use that for comparison. In case of equality, you won't escape comparing each element pairwise, whatever data structure you might use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your elements have a simple ordering function, and you know that they are distinct, then you will always be better off putting them in a vector and sorting them. In theory, a hash-table based solution with a good hash function could make the comparison O(n) rather than O(n log n), but there are a number of mitigating facts:

- **log** *n* is a small number. If n is two thousand million, for example, **log** *n* is 31 (using binary logs, which is usually what are implied).
- A standard library unordered collection requires an allocation for each element. This is effectively required by the specification because adding elements to an unordered collection does not invalidate references to existing elements, unlike the case with an standard library vector.
- Iteration over an unordered collection is done per bucket (again, this is in the specification), with the result that the iteration involves random memory access. Iterating over a vector is sequential, which is much more cache-friendly.

In short, even though the sort is O(n log n), it is highly likely that the O(n) hash-based solution has a large per-element constant, and since log n is a small number, the vector-based solution will be faster. Often much faster.

How much slower a hash-based solution will be depends on the speed of the allocator, and there is considerable variation between different standard library implementations. But even a super-rapid allocator is unlikely to give you competitive performance, and the cache-unfriendliness of the hash table will become important when your tables grow sufficiently large.

Even if you have some duplicate elements, you might be better off with the vector, but that will depend on how many duplicates you have. Since the hash table is likely to occupy at least twice as much memory as the vector with the same number of elements, a simple rule of thumb might be to use vectors as long as you don't expect the number of elements to be more than twice the number of unique elements. (It is easy to eliminate duplicates after sorting. There is a standard library function which will do that.)

Comment: rici- you got the problem statement correct "OP means that the containers are not modified after creation, rather than that all the containers are created at program initialization. " I will take this answer and @gd1 's suggestion as accurate. Thanks